# Delete records with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table over which I have built an ETL service. Goods records (arrival / departure) go to the table. I have done that my table will be erased. When the item identifier arrives in the database for the second time, both records are deleted.

```
label   cost   time
x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

Now ETL service remove records (every 30s):

```
label   cost   time
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
```

I delete it using the function:

```
with todelete as (
      select *, count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time DESC) as r_number
      from Table1
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt >= 2
```

I just need to make a small change right now. When, for example, during those 30 seconds I get the second record in the table, but also the third that the goods have arrived again.

```
        label   cost   time
        x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
        x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
        x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:02
        x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:22
```

In this case, I would lose the last record of the arrival of the goods. So I need to adjust the delete function. I've tried this, but it doesn't work properly.

```
with todelete as (
      select *
              , count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt
              , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time DESC) as r_number
      from Table1
     )
delete from todelete
    where (cnt = 2 OR cnt = 4) OR (cnt = 3 AND r_number > 1);
```

Would anyone help me to modify that function please.

**UPDATE:**
Exactly table:
Step1:

```
label   cost   time
x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
x2       29    15/5/2020 03:12:02
```

Step2:
Delete row with function:

```
with todelete as (
      select *, count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time DESC) as r_number
      from Table1
     )
delete from todelete
    where cnt >= 2
```

My goal is described above, but one more thing that affects is when it comes to moving with a change in price like this:

```
  label   cost   time
    x2       29    14/5/2020 01:00:00
    x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
    x2       30    15/5/2020 03:12:22
```

And then ETL deleted the old record and left the one with the new price.

```
        label   cost   time
        x3       20    14/5/2020 01:02:00
        x2       30    15/5/2020 03:12:22
```

This fact complicates it even more.

Comment: I didn't get the point. During the time ETL process tries to delete the records with `cnt >= 2`  will delete all rows for a `label` where it has more than one record. How does it make difference by adding  `(cnt = 2 OR cnt = 4) OR (cnt = 3 AND r_number > 1)` ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Because if the records for departure and arrival arrive during those 30 seconds, all records will be deleted after going through the ETL. And I need the third record to be preserved.

Comment: Ahh  You are right. Completely make sense and thanks for your nice clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try something like this.

**Explanation:**

Notice that I changed from DESC to ASC in the row_number() function's order by clause.

with this I delete the first arriving rows till the rows are even.
if Cnt=3 then (cnt/2)*2=2 as cnt is integer(note integer/2 gives integer not a fraction)

when cnt=4 then (cnt/2)*2 gives back 4.

```
with todelete as (
      select *, count(*) over (partition by label) as cnt, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by label order by time ASC) as r_number
      from Table1
     )
delete from todelete 
    where cnt > 1 and r_number between 1 and (cnt/2)*2
```